# xcode complaints that a file is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I just upgraded to `Xcode` 6.0.1, and ran into this interesting issue.

1. In `Xcode`, when I built this existing project, it complained that a file called create_SOF_account.png was missing.
2. When I looked at the files added to the project, it showed a ! mark besides file create_sof_account.png. However when I highlighted that file, the image showed up alright.
3. I double checked using terminal, I see a file called create_sof_account.png, and there was no create_SOF_account.png.
4. In my code, the following code works:

   ```
   [self setUpButton:self.button1 withWidth:296.0 withImage:@"create_SOF_account.png"];
   ```

But this does not work:

```
    [self setUpButton:self.button1 withWidth:296.0 withImage:@"create_sof_account.png"];
```

It does not really do any harm, since at least one option in above point 4 works, but it bothers me and would like to know the cause and the way to get rid of this warning. (This is an existing project and this warning did not exist before the `Xcode` upgrade.)

I tried to delete the reference from the project and added it back again, and that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Delete the app from the simulator/device. Do a clean build in Xcode. Then build and run again. You should get the right file with the matching name.

Comment: Are you using any version control like git? because `!` might be a conflict symbol.

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode right click on your project and select show in finder and see if any file with the name "create_SOF_account.png" exists.

Comment: create_SOF_account.png does this file exists in finder ?